# Javascript - JSON string replacement

Tags: javascript, string, json

With some help from fellow stack users I currently have this:

> http://jsfiddle.net/XRCvE/

I would like to know what I need to do to edit the code to change the JSON data {location.city} to delete after the first comma so this:

> Mansfield, MA, US

becomes

> Mansfield

Apologies, I am a beginner, a working jsfiddle would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
if (events[0].location.city.indexOf(',') > 0) {
  events[0].location.city =
      events[0].location.city.substr(0, events[0].location.city.indexOf(','));
}
```

I've updated the JSFiddle with a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/XRCvE/1/

Answer (score 3):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwfiorini/YzJ4t/)

Just do a split on the `,` and take the first item:

```
events[0].location.city = events[0].location.city.split(",")[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(events[0].location.city.indexOf(',') > 0) {
    events[0].location.city = events[0].location.city.split(",")[0];
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XRCvE/4/

Comment: +1 for `split()` instead of `indexOf()`; to me, using the former is a lot cleaner, and much more obvious as to what the code does than using `indexOf()`.